# why is this still need to cast in java?

Tags: java, generics

error

```
public class DefaultLiteProcessScopeFactory<S extends DefaultLiteProcessScope> implements LiteProcessScopeFactory<S> {
    @Override
    public S build() {
        return new DefaultLiteProcessScope();
    }
}
```

right

```
public class DefaultLiteProcessScopeFactory<S extends DefaultLiteProcessScope> implements LiteProcessScopeFactory<S> {
    @Override
    public S build() {
        return (S) new DefaultLiteProcessScope();
    }
}
```

DefaultLiteProcessScope extends DefaultLiteProcessScope,but it is till need to be cast?why?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Can you please use shorter names (a few letters) for your classes so your question is clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing here is wrong. You want to return some subtype of `DefaultLiteProcessScope` from the `build` method. However, you hard code the return type like this: `new DefaultLiteProcessScope()`. Now think of a slightly contrived example like this.

```
static class SubType extends DefaultLiteProcessScope {
        
}
```

And a client code that follows.

```
final LiteProcessScopeFactory<SubType> f = new DefaultLiteProcessScopeFactory<>();
final SubType result = f.build();
```

Now, since you have hard-coded the return type your compiler can't vouch for the type safety of the code. I wanted it to return the sub type, however you have hard-coded the super-type instead. So, it asks you to add an explicit cast, which is fair, isn't it? In fact, this cast fails at runtime throwing a `java.lang.ClassCastException` since super type `DefaultLiteProcessScope` cannot be cast to the subtype `SubType`.

**How to fix.**

A much better approach would be to pass in a supplier to your build method as an argument like so.

```
static class DefaultLiteProcessScopeFactory<S extends DefaultLiteProcessScope> implements LiteProcessScopeFactory<S> {
    @Override
    public S build(Supplier<S> s) {
        return s.get();
    }
}

static interface LiteProcessScopeFactory<S> {
    S build(Supplier<S> s);
}
```

Here's the new client code.

```
final LiteProcessScopeFactory<SubType> f = new DefaultLiteProcessScopeFactory<>();
final SubType result = f.build(SubType::new);
```

Comment: If you are telling the factory how to build the object, via the `Supplier<T>`, whats the point of the factory, you've lost all abstraction if the client defines how to build it? A better approach would be for the client to define what `Class<T>` to build and let the Factory create.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that the code is wrong.

```
public class MyOtherFactory<SubclassOfDefaultLiteProcessScope> {}
```

will break because DefaultLiteProcessScope is not a SubclassOfDefaultLiteProcessScope.

Comment: you means that the extends keyword do not include itself?

Comment: @DavidRicardo No, that's not what I mean. I mean extends can be a subclass. If S is a subclass of DefaultLiteProcessScope, then returning a DefaultLiteProcessScope is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Your code would throw a `ClassCastException` in the following instance:

```
class CustomLiteProcessScope extends DefaultLiteProcessScope { ... }

final DefaultLiteProcessScopeFactory<CustomLiteProcessScope> factory = new ...;
```

And then:

```
factory.build(); <-- Exception trying to cast DefaultLiteProcessScope to CustomLiteProcessScope
```

Answer (score 2):

`S` extends `DefaultLiteProcessScope`, so you're trying to return the parent class instance instead of child class instance.